# DateTime is one month off when formatting?

Tags: oop, datetime, php-5.4

I ran into this, and thought my server was crazy, but after testing it in
[Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7OzunP) I run into the same results. After using Datetime to try and
process my date stamp I end up one day and one month OFF my original date
after trying to format back to a string?? What madness is going on here?

Here's the code

```
echo $obj->attributes->timestamp; // output: Jun 25, 2013 11:43:52:875 AM

$date = New \DateTime();

$date->createFromFormat(
    'M j, Y h:i:s:B A',
    $obj->attributes->timestamp
);

echo $date->format('M j, Y'); // output: Jul 24, 2013
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`public static DateTime DateTime::createFromFormat ( string $format , string $time [, DateTimeZone $timezone ] )`

It is static and returns new `DateTime`, but you are not using returned value but current date created by calling `DateTime` empty constructor.

Example from [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#example-634), how to use it properly:

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```